# Effects of concurrent accesses on a HashSet

Tags: java, collections, synchronization, hashset

I ran into some shady piece of code in which a `HashSet` is accessed and modified by several threads at the same time, and I wanted to know what effects this could have had, considering the Javadoc only explains the behavior is "non-deterministic" under concurrent, unsynchronized accesses.

Specifically, is it possible that a call to `remove(element)` returns `true`, but that the effects of the call are never ever seen by other threads (ie. `contains(element)` will always return `true` in other threads) ?

PS: Just to reassure you, I know this code is bad and I will replace the `HashSet` with an equivalent synchronized collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accessing HashSet in multiple threads can.

- result in a change you make not being seen by another thread.
- an Iterator to fail with a ConcurrentModifcationException.
- a thread to go into an infinite loop inside HashSet code (rare but pretty bad when it does)

Note: a simple replacement is to use

```
Set<Type> set = Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<Type, Boolean>());
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Peter ! Could you just clarify something for me ? When you a say "a change not being seen by another thread", is it assumed that the change will be seen eventually, or is it possible that the effect of a change are discarded indefinitely for one (or more) thread ?

Comment: I usually assume as a rule of thumb that gods of concurrency hate us and worst possible things can happen

Comment: @ahelix There's simply no guarantee. The results will definitely not be discarded, but the visibility may be indefinitely postponed. A worse aspect is that various individual modifications may become visible at different times, resulting in a completely broken `HashSet` object.

Comment: @ahelix It is quite likely that a change is lost forever unless you have one writer and multiple readers (in this case it should be eventually consistent) If you have multiple writers than can clobber each other's changes.